# Should we specify the version of the base docker image in Dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am building a sprint boot application and using Docker to deploy it.

In the Dockerfile, I have the first line as this

```
FROM alpine
```

So my question here is, should I specify a tag on the alpine image like `FROM alpine:3.9` or should I leave it without any version. (I've read somewhere that using `:latest` is a bad idea but didn't understand why)

Comment: There's a related question at [devops.se]: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/4454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mention the version it will pull the latest version of your mentioned image.

###### Why you should avoid using images with latest tag

- Imagine one of your colleague used base image with tag alpine:1.0.0 and you are using image alpine:latest which will pull alpine:3.x.x. Because of this inconsistency You would be ended up breaking your application.
- You should avoid using the :latest tag when deploying containers in production, because this makes it hard to track which version of the image is running and hard to roll back. Also if something goes wrong in production you won't be able to track which version of your releases causing the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying version tag or even the image digest is a good practice regarding [reproducible builds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds).

`latest` tag content changes from time to time, making it impossible for you to build the same artifact/image from the same Dockerfile.